# Как организовать подсчет на C++ с данной формулой ?

Tags: c++

[image: Формула]

Нужно произвести расчет по данной формуле с функциями Cout, cin.

Comment: Тангенс - `tan`, квадратный корень - `sqrt`. Дальше - самостоятельно... Когда будут конкретные вопросы, а не "сделайте за меня" - тогда и спрашивайте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    cout << "Введите x:" << endl:
    cin >> x;
    y = sqrt(1 + fabs(tan(pow(x,2))));
    cout << "Резулатат:" << y << endl;
```